# Need ribbon control common in all window/page in wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf

I am goin to do a project in WPF c#. I am really new to this.

I would like to know whether it is possible to have common ribbon control for all window/pages(similar mdi parent window in win application).

Do wpf have parent mdi window to acheive this.

And really what is the difference between pages and windows. which should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is WPF Ribbon Control Application.

For starting take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ribbondemo.aspx) project